# How to change Color from Slider on Xamarin Mac Platform?

Tags: colors, xamarin.forms, slider, xamarin.mac, custom-renderer

The default color from a Slider on Xamarin Mac project is blue, I want to change it to green, So I have made a Custom Renderer, but unfortunately, I don't what to do inside the custom renderer, How can I change the color?

```
using CustomSliderColor.MacOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSlider), typeof(CustomSliderRenderer))]
namespace CustomSliderColor.MacOS
{
    public class CustomSliderRenderer : SliderRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                //What do I put here?????
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to subclass NSSlider and draw the bar yourself (In DrawRect...and DrawCell(?) i think, it has been awhile since I did it myself.) and then use that subclass in your renderer.

Comment: I found some examples to subclass NSSliderCell, If you have an example about how to subclass NSSlider please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question.

First subclass the "NSSliderCell" class, here an example:

```
using System;
using AppKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;

namespace myproject.MacOs
{
    public class CustomSliderCell : NSSliderCell 
    {
        public override void DrawBar(CGRect aRect, Boolean flipped)
        {
            CGRect rect = aRect;
            rect.Size = new CGSize(rect.Size.Width, 5);
            float barRadius = 2.5f;
            double value = (double)((this.DoubleValue - this.MinValue) / (this.MaxValue - this.MinValue));
            float finalWidth = (float)(value * (this.ControlView.Frame.Size.Width - 8));
            CGRect leftRect = rect;
            leftRect.Size = new CGSize(finalWidth, leftRect.Size.Height);
            NSBezierPath bg = new NSBezierPath();
            bg.AppendPathWithRoundedRect(rect, barRadius, barRadius);
            NSColor.FromRgb(0, 160, 0).SetFill();
            bg.Fill();
            NSBezierPath active = new NSBezierPath();
            active.AppendPathWithRoundedRect(leftRect, barRadius, barRadius);
            NSColor.FromRgb(0,128,0).SetFill();
            active.Fill();
        }

    }
}
```

Then in your customSlider renderer on Mac

```
using AppKit;
using CustomSliderColor.MacOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using myproject;
using myproject.MacOs;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSlider), typeof(CustomSliderRenderer))]
namespace CustomSliderColor.MacOS
{
    public class CustomSliderRenderer : SliderRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Slider> e)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                NSSlider customNSSlider = new NSSlider();
                CustomSliderCell custom = new CustomSliderCell();
                customNSSlider.Cell = custom;
                SetNativeControl(customNSSlider);
            }
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you have it!!!

[image]